# Xcode/firebase, swift 3 encryption

Tags: swift, firebase, encryption, firebase-realtime-database

I need to encrypt some of the data I collect before it goes up to the database. I figured out how, using RNCryptor and Crytoswift. 
The problem is that the key to encrypt and decrypt the data, must be from on the database.

I can´t get it to work.
This is the code:

```
@IBAction func Encrypt(_ sender: Any) {
    let input = stringFirst.text
    let key = keyFirst.text
    let iv = keyFirst.text
    let en = try! input!.aesEncrypt(key: key!, iv: iv!)
    outputFirst.text = en
}

extension String{
func aesEncrypt(key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
    let data = self.data(using: .utf8)!
    let encrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).encrypt([UInt8](data))
    let encryptedData = Data(encrypted)
    return encryptedData.base64EncodedString()
}
```

As it is now, the key can be written from the user but I need it to be the same key and taken from firebase database.
I tried something like:

```
self.databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("key").child(self.otherUser?["key"] as! String).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let uid = self.otherUser?["key"] as! String
        self.otherUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.otherUser?.setValue(uid, forKey: "key")

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
    key = self.otherUser?["key"] as? String
```

UPDATE!

I added this code to ViewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("encryption").child(self.otherUser?["key"] as! String).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let uid = self.otherUser?["key"] as! String
        self.otherUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.otherUser?.setValue(uid, forKey: "key")

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
    key1 = self.otherUser?["key"] as? String
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The error now is EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION, the marked line is:

```
databaseRef.child("encryption").child(self.otherUser?["key"] as! String).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

It acts like it isnt connected to firebase, but I checked everything and it is connected?

Comment: Well, it's non trivial logic, so hard to say what gone wrong. Two comments:

Error is quite explicit, you get UIint, not String. If you are sure that this string should be from that number, you can create new String from number.

Are you sure you want to store encryption key along with encrypted data? Or maybe I just don't understand your case without more context ;)

Comment: Hello, well I need it so that a person can´t access the data with only the phone. If I use a textfield to insert the key, it all works fine. The thing is just how I get from the database and into my code.
FYI: The key is all random text and numbers.

Comment: So you need to debug what do you get from database ;) If your return type is UIint, and key is alphanumerical, you clearly get wrong filed. I don't know your databse schema, so hard to say. PS. if user get key from database (which shouldn't be a problem) he can easily decrypt all data.

Comment: Im new, what do you need me to do? :)

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but you really should learn how to debug such errors yourself ;) There are plenty of tutorials about that (https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/xcode-debugging-with-breakpoints-for-beginners-5b0d0a39d711 is one of the first from google).
You should also look at database scheme (and read tutorial if you don't understand it) and compare to your code. Feel free to ask when you have more specific question!

Comment: Ofc, but I know the error? "Cannot convert type of "UInt" to expected type "String"

Comment: I just updated my question, this might be more accurate?